# Assign unique ids to <div> inside <c:forEach>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jstl

I want to assign a unique id for the `<div>` enclosed in the `<c:forEach>`. Whenever the page is rendered all the `<div>`s generated by the `<c:forEach>` have the same id. Is there any way to assign unique id for all the divs generated by the `<c:forEach>`? I have tried using `<ui:repeat>` but I was having issues with it so I decided to stick with `<c:forEach>`.

Facelet:

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="#{statusBean.statusList}">
    <h:form>
        <div class="status">
            // Content
        </div>
    </h:form>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `c:forEach` attribute `varStatus` to define a variable that will contain [the status of the loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html). Then you can use it in your template like this:

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="#{statusBean.statusList}" varStatus="loop">
        <h:form>
            <div class="status_#{loop.count}">
            // Content
            </div>
        </h:form>
</c:forEach>
```

You can also use `#{loop.index}` if you want it initiated with 0.

Comment: Ooh... that's way better than my cruddy answer!

Comment: @jahroy I think so too, but I had the same initial thought as you: "why isn't that a panelGroup?" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `<h:panelGroup>` or another JSF component to render your divs.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/

This will cause unique IDs to get generated for you.

Comment: How will I know the ids of the divs beforehand because I want to use the ids in javascript.

Comment: That's not possible to answer without seeing your code and knowing what you want to do.  Generally you would look at the generated HTML (with a debugger) and figure out how to manipulate it.  For the record, I think the answer by @elias is far superior to mine.  With his suggestion you would have significant control over the ids.